# How to detect browser close alone and refresh is not a part of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i want to detect browser close alone in javascript. The below code am using is detecting the browser close as well as refresh, back etc.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (evt) {
  var message = 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
  if (typeof evt == 'undefined') {
    evt = window.event;
  }
  if (evt) {
    evt.returnValue = message;
  }
  return evt;
}
```

Comment: Clarify what you mean by "detect browser close alone"?

Comment: when i close the browser alone i want to call a function..

Comment: @hindmost probably that means detecting only "close" event, not refresh or back etc.

Comment: @Andrei yes you are right..

Comment: AFAIK you cannot detect such situation

Comment: @Ajith you can only have some variable and set it to true/false in different situations. In `onbeforeunload` you can check that variable and decide what happened.

Comment: This is a bad practice (Are you sure? - YES, I was clicked X!), only reasonable use for me is blocking window when you writing message. Anyway I think that you can combine this event with click, this could help to eliminate 70-80% unwanted alerts. Other idea is to use html5 history management and reload content of pages with AJAX for local links [Manipulating the browser history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). Just some ideas and feel free to do something ambitious ;)

Comment: I dont think this is duplicate..Browser Refresh detect is entirely different from browser close detect..